# DDD and EF, sharing entities between different bounded context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

One DDD Bounded context refers to one EF DbContext to keep things easy and clean.
How to deal with entities that can be used from different bounded context?
For exemple the Person table defined in HumanResource DbContext is usefull to report and view in ohers context.
We tried the reference context patter to solve this problems but now we have the class rappresenting the table person in all our DDD Context and we have to sync all  his property.

Answer (score 2):

You should translate the object model from remote Bounded contexts to local Bounded context.

The `Person` from the HR Bounded context should not be used as it is in the local Bounded context, but `converted` to a (simpler) object, named accordingly to the Ubiquitous language from the local Bounded context, i.e. `Employee` or `Payer` or whatever local domain you have.

For this there are more [integration technics](https://www.culttt.com/2014/11/26/strategies-integrating-bounded-contexts/). One of them is the Anti-corruption layer. You could have for example a scheduled task or cron job that fetches all the Persons and saved them in a local cache as local objects; local objects have in general fewer properties as the remote objects and no update logic. They are in general implemented as Value objects.

The best integration technics is to use integration events. Every time a Person is updated the remote Bounded context publishes an event to all interested Bounded contexts that react to these events and update their local cache.

So, in other words, it is not recommended to directly reference the database tables from remote Bounded contexts.

Comment: I second this.  If an aggregate in BC *A* is required in BC *B* it should be represented in BC *B* using either only the *identifier* or a *value object*.  As Constantin mentioned any extra data (other than the identifier) would need to be kept in sync and an *event-driven architecture* (probably using a service bus / messaging system) would be a big win here.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but to refresh my cache i need to query my ef DbContext and i will have the same issue, am i wrong? My main problem is that the two DbContext share the table "Person" and if we change a column name we have to change all the Context that uses the person table.

Comment: @AntonioCampagnaro yes, but this is normal, when you change a column then you have to change all the users of that column. However, with what I'm proposing (using a ACL) you won't have to change the Domain code from other Bounded contexts, only the ACL. In DDD, the Domain is the most important and we try to protect it.